# Efficient way to retrieve all _ids in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the fastest way to get all _ids of a certain index from ElasticSearch? Is it possible by using a simple query? One of my index has around 20,000 documents.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17159) very helpful.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

*Edit: Please also read the [answer from Aleck Landgraf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855670/1164465)*

You just want the elasticsearch-internal `_id` field? Or an `id` field from within your documents?

For the former, try

```
curl http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search?pretty=true -d '
{ 
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {} 
    },
    "stored_fields": []
}
'
```

If you are using Elastic dev tools, use this instead:

```
GET <your-index-name>/_search
{ 
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {} 
    },
    "stored_fields": []
}
```

**Note 2017 Update:** The post originally included `"fields": []` but since then the name has changed and `stored_fields` is the new value.

The result will contain only the "metadata" of your documents

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "36",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "38",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "39",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "34",
      "_score" : 1.0
    } ]
  }
}
```

For the latter, if you want to include a field from your document, simply add it to the `fields` array

```
curl http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search?pretty=true -d '
{ 
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {} 
    },
    "fields": ["document_field_to_be_returned"]
}
'
```

Comment: Won't this return just 10 results ?

Comment: Doing a straight query is not the most efficient way to do this.  When you do a query, it has to sort all the results before returning it.  Scroll and Scan mentioned in response below will be much more efficient, because it does not sort the result set before returning it.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in 5.x, field `fields` was removed, instead, add `"_source": false` param.

Comment: "field" is not supported in this query anymore by elasticsearch. use "stored_field" instead

Comment: This will not return ids. For me trying on Elasticsearch 8.7, it returns 10000 results.

Answer (score 57):

Better to use [scroll and scan](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-request-scroll.html#scroll-scan) to get the result list so elasticsearch doesn't have to rank and sort the results.

With the `elasticsearch-dsl` python lib this can be accomplished by:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search

es = Elasticsearch()
s = Search(using=es, index=ES_INDEX, doc_type=DOC_TYPE)

s = s.fields([])  # only get ids, otherwise `fields` takes a list of field names
ids = [h.meta.id for h in s.scan()]
```

Console log:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_doc/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=5m [status:200 request:0.003s]
GET http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=5m [status:200 request:0.005s]
GET http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=5m [status:200 request:0.005s]
GET http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=5m [status:200 request:0.003s]
GET http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=5m [status:200 request:0.005s]
...
```

*Note*: **scroll** pulls batches of results from a query and keeps the cursor open for a given amount of time (1 minute, 2 minutes, which you can update); **scan** disables sorting. The `scan` helper function returns a python generator which can be safely iterated through.

Comment: Method `fields` has been removed in version `5.0.0` (see: https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog.html?highlight=fields(#id2). You should now use `s = s.source([]) `.

Comment: the given link is not available. Showing 404

Comment: search_type=scan deprecated since 2.1. ([https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_21_search_changes.html](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/breaking_21_search_changes.html))

Answer (score 25):

For elasticsearch 5.x, you can use the "[_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)" field.

```
GET /_search
{
    "_source": false,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

`"fields"` has been deprecated.
(Error: "The field [fields] is no longer supported, please use [stored_fields] to retrieve stored fields or _source filtering if the field is not stored")

Comment: Bonus points for adding the error text. Elasticsearch error messages mostly don't seem to be very googlable :(

Answer (score 17):

Elaborating on answers by [Robert Lujo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34832944/1164465) and [Aleck Landgraf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30855670/1164465),
if you want the IDs in a list from the returned generator, here is what I use:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers


es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[YOUR_ES_HOST])
hits = helpers.scan(
    es,
    query={"query":{"match_all": {}}},
    scroll='1m',
    index=INDEX_NAME
)
    
ids = [hit['_id'] for hit in hits]
```

Answer (score 13):

Another option

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search?pretty=true&fields='
```

will return _index, _type, _id and _score.

Comment: -1 Better to use scan and scroll when accessing more than just a few documents.   This is a "quick way" to do it, but won't perform well and also might fail on large indices

Comment: On 6.2: "request ... contains unrecognized parameter: [fields]"

Comment: Is there any way to get only _id field?

Comment: `stored_fields` instead of `fields` for newer versions

Answer (score 6):

I know this post has a lot of answers, but I want to combine several to document what I've found to be fastest (in Python anyway). I'm dealing with hundreds of millions of documents, rather than thousands.

The `helpers` class can be used with [sliced scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#sliced-scroll) and thus allow multi-threaded execution. In my case, I have a high cardinality field to provide (`acquired_at`) as well. You'll see I set `max_workers` to 14, but you may want to vary this depending on your machine.

Additionally, I store the doc ids in compressed format. If you're curious, [you can check how many bytes your doc ids will be](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#how%20many%20bytes%20is%20this) and estimate the final dump size.

```py
# note below I have es, index, and cluster_name variables already set

max_workers = 14
scroll_slice_ids = list(range(0,max_workers))

def get_doc_ids(scroll_slice_id):
    count = 0
    with gzip.open('/tmp/doc_ids_%i.txt.gz' % scroll_slice_id, 'wt') as results_file:
        query = {"sort": ["_doc"], "slice": { "field": "acquired_at", "id": scroll_slice_id, "max": len(scroll_slice_ids)+1}, "_source": False}
        scan = helpers.scan(es, index=index, query=query, scroll='10m', size=10000, request_timeout=600)
        for doc in scan:
            count += 1
            results_file.write((doc['_id'] + '\n'))
            results_file.flush()

    return count 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('attempting to dump doc ids from %s in %i slices' % (cluster_name, len(scroll_slice_ids)))
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        doc_counts = executor.map(get_doc_ids, scroll_slice_ids)
```

If you want to follow along with how many ids are in the files, you can use `unpigz -c /tmp/doc_ids_4.txt.gz | wc -l`.

Comment: Is it possible to use multiprocessing approach but skip the files and query ES directly?

Comment: Of course, you just remove the lines related to saving the output of the queries into the file (anything with `results_file` var).

Comment: For some reason it returns as many document id's as many workers I set. So if I set 8 workers it returns only 8 ids

Answer (score 3):

For Python users: the [Python Elasticsearch client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#scan) provides a convenient abstraction for the scroll API:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
client = Elasticsearch()

query = {
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}

scan = helpers.scan(client, index=index, query=query, scroll='1m', size=100)

for doc in scan:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do it in python, which gives you a proper list:

```
import elasticsearch
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()

res = es.search(
    index=your_index, 
    body={"query": {"match_all": {}}, "size": 30000, "fields": ["_id"]})

ids = [d['_id'] for d in res['hits']['hits']]
```

Comment: question was "Efficient way to retrieve all _ids in ElasticSearch". You set it to 30000 ... What if you have 4000000000000000 records!!!???

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @Aleck-Landgraf answer, for me it worked by using directly [scan](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html?highlight=scan#elasticsearch.helpers.scan) function in standard elasticsearch python API:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan
es = Elasticsearch()
for dobj in scan(es, 
                 query={"query": {"match_all": {}}, "fields" : []},  
                 index="your-index-name", doc_type="your-doc-type"): 
        print dobj["_id"],
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a neat tool like elasticdump and issue a query like the following:

```
~/.bin/elasticdump --input='http://username:password@myelasticsearch.dev:9200/my-index' --output=output.txt --searchBody='{"_source": ["_id"], "query":{ "match_all": {}}}' --limit 10000
```

then you can process the output.txt file using the `cut` linux command and get only the id part for each document

Answer (score 0):

This is working!

```
def select_ids(self, **kwargs):
    """

    :param kwargs:params from modules
    :return: array of incidents
    """
    index = kwargs.get('index')
    if not index:
        return None

    # print("Params", kwargs)
    query = self._build_query(**kwargs)
    # print("Query", query)

    # get results
    results = self._db_client.search(body=query, index=index, stored_fields=[], filter_path="hits.hits._id")
    print(results)
    ids = [_['_id'] for _ in results['hits']['hits']]
    return ids
```

Answer (score -4):

```
Url -> http://localhost:9200/<index>/<type>/_query
http method -> GET
Query -> {"query": {"match_all": {}}, "size": 30000, "fields": ["_id"]}
```

Comment: inefficient, especially if the query was able to fetch documents more than 10000